# SQL - Invalid column name when executing in DAO

Tags: java, spring, oracle, plsql, spring-jdbc

I'm doing a query on my Spring Application that will select data on my database based on this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT a.*, rownum r__
        FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS WHERE status = 'active' and is_blocked = 'N'
        ) a
        WHERE rownum < ((1 * 3) + 1 )
    )
WHERE r__ >= (((1-1) * pageSize) + 1)
```

The goal is to simply page on results.

When I'm executing the code on my database query windows I got the expected results but when executing directly in java code as usually I got  this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM(    SELECT
>   a.*, rownum r__    FROM    (        SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS
>   WHERE status = 'active' and is_blocked = 'N'    ) a    WHERE rownum <
>   ((? * ?) + 1 ))WHERE r__ >= (((?-1) * ?) + 1)]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

I do not understand why that returns this error because my query works when executed on the Oracle SQL Client...

To execute my query I do this:

```
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        params.addValue("pageSize", paging.getItemsPerPage());
        params.addValue("pageNumber", paging.getPageToFetch());
        SqlQueryLogger.logDebugSqlQuery(selectActiveAndUnblockedSubscriptionPaged, params, log);

        List<Subscription> subscriptions = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().query(selectActiveAndUnblockedSubscriptionPaged, params, new SubscriptionRowMapper());
        SubscriptionPagingResult subscriptionPagingResult = new SubscriptionPagingResult();
        subscriptionPagingResult.setResult(subscriptions);
```

and the selectActiveAndUnblockedSubscriptionPaged variable is :

```
"SELECT * FROM" +
            "(" +
            "    SELECT a.*, rownum r__" +
            "    FROM" +
            "    (" +
            "        SELECT * FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS WHERE status = 'active' and is_blocked = 'N'" +
            "    ) a" +
            "    WHERE rownum < ((:pageNumber * :pageSize) + 1 )" +
            ")" +
            "WHERE r__ >= (((:pageNumber-1) * :pageSize) + 1)";
```

Does anyone have an idea why this code does not work ?
Thank you

Comment: The error message is quite straightforward so maybe start looking for invalid column names by replacing the `*` with actual column names from `SUBSCRIPTIONS`, maybe a few at a time. And of course check `r__`, maybe this is the one to start with.

Comment: When I replace * by column names on my query I got a new error :
ambiguous column definition that highlight the a.* on the second select.
Do you have an idea ?
Thank you!

Comment: Exact error is this one:  
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: I was going to write about the missing alias mentioned in the answer below but forgot. Maybe start there to see if it helps

Comment: What is a PL/SQL Client? I don't see any PL/SQL, just SQL.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson : I already did it but no helps unfortunately
WilliamRobertson : I said PL/SQL Client but it is simply my Oracle SQL client. We have PL/SQL in our DB but not on my case sorry will rename subject :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion you missed the table alias  after thr main from ()

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(
    SELECT a.*, a.rownum r__
    FROM
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM SUBSCRIPTIONS 
        WHERE status = 'active' 
        and is_blocked = 'N'
    ) a
    WHERE a.rownum < ((1 * 3) + 1 )
) t 
WHERE t.r__ >= (((1-1) * t.pageSize) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately that was not the error but I added the forgotten alias it is better :-)

Comment: @DupuisDavid  answer  updated  adding table alias for all the columns  involved ..but be sure you have not a  rownum column in your subscribtions table too